# sproutcore property(@each) is not updating

Tags: javascript, binding, each, sproutcore

I'm analyzing the basic [todo](http://sproutcore.com/guides/getting_started.html) application.

Why is it that when I delete the `StatsView` (from the main todos.js and from todos.handlebars) the `remaining` method (property) of the `todoListController` stops updating itself?

```
Todos.todoListController = SC.ArrayController.create({
  ...
  remaining: function() {
    console.log('remaining');//doesn't apear in the console
    return this.filterProperty('isDone', false).get('length');
  }.property('@each.isDone').cacheable(),
  ...
});
```

I can imagine, that this is because with the `StatsView` I deleted the binding. But shouldn't it be, that the `@each` keeps an eye on the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SproutCore optimizes to do as little work as possible. So, when you deleted the StatsView, you deleted the thing that cares about the `.remaining` property. Since nothing is asking for it, SproutCore doesn't compute it. This is why you should always use the `get()` and `set()` methods when accessing properties so that they can decide whether to use the cached version or to actually compute the property.